# If, Else, setText trouble

Tags: java, settext

I am currently trying to handle what happens with results if there is input received and coming across some troubles, I want to be able to set the text to a specific phrase if there is no result, and want to be able to have the input show correctly if there is. I am currently trying **this:**

```
String s = scanningResult.getContents();
    if (s == null){ 
        s="Location Is here,Time is here,Cost is here";
    }
    else {
        s=s;
    }
    String [] s2 = s.split(",");

    TextView location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LocationResult);
    location.setText(s2[0]);


    TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TimeResult);
    if (s2[1] == "Time is here"){ 
        time.setText("Time is here");
    }
    else {
        time.setText(s2[1]+" Seconds");
    }


    TextView cost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CostResult);
    if (s2[2] == "Cost is here"){ 
        cost.setText("Cost is here");
    }
    else {
        cost.setText("$"+s2[2]);
    }

}
```

The problem i am having is that on a `null scanningResult` the two values `time` and `cost` will come out as `Time is here Seconds` and `$Cost is here`. And i don't see why.

Comment: did you debug the code on a null scanningResult ? To see if the s is really null ? 

By the way you should do the check by : 

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))

Comment: Check what is inside `s2` directly after you assigned s2. Maybe you forgot to escape "," or the string has another format as you expected. So giving out `s` is a good idea, too. BTW, your first else is nonsense, what should `s=s;` do?

Comment: @hoangnnm ,To retrieve the null that i am testing i am simply canceling the scan which sets `scanningResult.getContents()` to null. If i make `String s = null;` it gives me the same result as a canceled scan

Comment: @usr1234567 What? And; I just put it in there as a fallback (Aka yes pointless just a habit)

Comment: @Tehjohn Than it is a bad habit. It confuses the reader and may introduce bugs for pointless code. Would you mind to change the title to be more meaningful?

Comment: All you need to do is very simple, like usr1234567 said, just check what is in s2 after you assigned it

Comment: Removed it and still no difference, What would you suggest for a title, I chose that cause i couldnt think of one

Comment: @hoangnnm, Could i have some example code, I dont quite understand what i am meant to do

Comment: MessageBox.Show(s2[1]) ???

Comment: @hoangnnm, Bills answer fixed the problem, Was just using the wrong method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Java use `equals` method to compare `String`

```
if (s2[1].equals("Time is here")){ }
```

Comment: Cant use text, has to be an object for .equal

Comment: @Tehjohn text is String and thus an object, just try it.

Comment: Additional explanations about @Bill's solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java.  Is it possible that () are missin arround the literal ?